# Overlapping music onclick + last clicked element

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a musical gallery using vanilla javascript. Each photo plays a different song `onclick`. 
Currently each click starts the song again in the background, so it can play as many times as clicked on. Also, all photos can play simultaneously. 
 I'm trying to figure out how to get only one song to play at a time and restart `onclick` rather than play over itself.

 I think the way to do it is to get the last click event and then `audio.pause()` all other songs but can't seem to figure out quite how to do it, would love some help.

 Thanks!

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <ul>
    <li id="1" class="pic"><img onclick="playSong('Avengers')" src="/Users/library /.vscode/musicalGallery/1_1.jpg" alt="scenery"></li>
    <li id="2" class="pic"><img onclick="playSong('River')" src="/Users/library/.vscode/musicalGallery/2.jpg" alt="scenery"></li>
    <li id="3" class="pic"><img onclick="playSong('Sail')" src="/Users/library/.vscode/musicalGallery/3_3.jpg" alt="scenery"></li>
    <li id="4" class="pic"><img onclick="playSong('Warfare')" src="/Users/library/.vscode/musicalGallery/4.jpg" alt="scenery"></li>
    <li id="5" class="pic"><img onclick="playSong('Joni')" src="/Users/library/.vscode/musicalGallery/5_5.jpg" alt="scenery"></li>
    <li id="6" class="pic"><img onclick="playSong('Wait')" src="/Users/library/.vscode/musicalGallery/6_6.jpg" alt="scenery"></li>
    <li id="7" class="pic"><img onclick="playSong('Suzanne')" src="/Users/library/.vscode/musicalGallery/7_7.jpg" alt="scenery"></li>
    <li id="8" class="pic"><img onclick="playSong('Bones')" src="/Users/library/.vscode/musicalGallery/8_8.jpg" alt="scenery"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

```js
function playSong(id) {
  var songSource = "/Users/library/Desktop/jqueryGallery/musicalGalleryMusic/" + id + ".mp3";
  var audio = new Audio(songSource);
  audio.play();
  audio.volume = 0.3;
};
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can create just one `var audio = new Audio()` separate from your function.  Then you should be able to: `audio.pause(); audio.src = "/Users/..."; audio.play();` in your `playSong` function, (as opposed to creating a new HTMLAudioElement every time as you do now). You should also be able to use `audio. currentTime = 0` to start the song from 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could scope your audio player outside of your function. You could then check to see if `audio.paused` is false to see if a song is currently playing, and pause it before changing the `src`.

```js
var audio = new Audio();
function playSong(id) {
  if (!audio.paused) {
    audio.pause();
  }
  audio.src = "/Users/library/Desktop/jqueryGallery/musicalGalleryMusic/" + id + ".mp3";
  audio.play();
  audio.volume = 0.3;
};
```

Comment: This works perfectly!
So much more simple than what I was going for. Thanks!

Comment: So eventually I learned that it works well without 
`if (!audio.paused) { audio.pause(); }`   part. Thank you!